# missing classes for toastr using angular 9

Tags: html, css, .net, angular

I had installed "ngx-toastr": "^14.0.0" in angular 9 application, but while working with toastr predefined classes and tags are missing in some child module, i had imported

```js
ToastrModule.forRoot({
   preventDuplicates: true
}),
```

in root module and imported ToasterService in components, I am unable to find the solution

added  css  in style.css

```css
#toast-container > div {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Toaster with inspect img:  [image: 1]

Toaster with missing classes and tags with inspect img: [image: 2]

Comment: If you have child modules, you need to import `ToastrModule` to them as well (leave the `forRoot` out)

Comment: i had tried using import with the child module as well as  but not working